# Mongoose populate a single virtual field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema (CoffeeScript):

```
adSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  user : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  ...
},
{
  toObject: { virtuals: true },
  toJSON: { virtuals: true }
})

userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username : String
  email :
    type : String
    required : true
    index :
      unique : true
  adverts : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Advert' }]
},
{
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
  toJSON: { virtuals: true }
})

userSchema.virtual('screenname').get () ->
  if this.username? then this.username else this.email.split('@')[0]+'@...'
```

Then I try to get a bunch of records and populate the user:

```
getAdvertPage = (obj, fn) ->
  page_size = 10
  query =
    tags : obj.tag
  Advert.count query, (err, count) ->
    Advert.find(query)
    .sort(obj.sort)
    .skip((obj.page-1)*page_size)
    .limit(page_size)
    .populate('user', 'screenname')
    .exec (err, ads) ->
      ads.lastPage = (obj.page-1)*page_size + page_size >= count
      fn err, ads
```

But I only want the user's screenname and nothing else (which is a virtual field). However, this results in an error:

```
Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
```

If I include the email in the populate it works fine, but I don't want to send the email to the client. Is there no way to populate only a virtual field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have dependancies on the fields 'email' and 'username' inside the virtual getter for 'screenname', try populating screenname, email and username.

```
...
.populate('user', 'screenname, email, username')
...
```

By the way, you should not implement business logic inside virtual getters to avoid situations like this. consider creating another virtual.

Comment: Yeah I know that including `email` and `username` in the populate will get this to work. However, I don't want to send the email to the client. I could just go through the results and remove the email before I send it to the client, but I really don't want some kind of hack.

Thanks for the tip on the business logic inside the virtual. I will look into that :)

Comment: But this approach populates _id as well which doesn't looks good